# re.sub only replacing two occurrences

Tags: python, regex

I am using re.sub but it is not replacing all occurrences.

```
re.sub(r'\b\s+\b', '.', string, re.I)
```

The first is the input and the second is the output.

```
a b c d e f g
a.b.c d e f g
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that one but it didn't help me.

Comment: Check this [invalid bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue15768)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the `re.I` flag, you should specify it as a keyword argument (or else it will be interpreted as being the value of `count` instead since `count` comes before `flags` in [the signature of `re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)).

```
>>> string = 'a b c d e f g'
>>> re.sub(r'\b\s+\b', '.', string, flags=re.I)
'a.b.c.d.e.f.g'
```

Alternatively, compile your regex first.

```
>>> string = 'a b c d e f g'
>>> my_re = re.compile(r'\b\s+\b', re.I)
>>> re.sub(my_re, '.', string)
'a.b.c.d.e.f.g'
```

Comment: `re.I` aka `re.IGNORECASE` is simply `2`, which `re.sub` interprets as a count parameter. Thus `re.sub(r'\b\s+\b', '.', string, flags=2)` is the same thing.

Comment: @jmu303 True, that is equivalent, but that would be a terrible thing to actually write in one's code.

Answer (score 7):

You were telling it to replace only 2 instances:

```
>>> re.I
2
>>> re.sub(r'\b\s+\b', '.', string)
'a.b.c.d.e.f.g'
```

Comment: Isn't re.I for ignore case?

Comment: This is it. `re.sub` takes the `count` parameter before the `flags` parameter. You can explicitly supply the default value of `0` to `count` (0 meaning unlimited, wtf?); or you can use a keyword argument (`flags=re.I`). IMO this interface needs a major overhaul; the re.I etc. constants are powers of 2 meant to be bitwise-OR'd together which is ridiculous in a language this high-level (why not just supply a string with the relevant 'AILMSUX' letters?), and in 3.x it ought to use keyword-only arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
'.'.join(input_str.split(' '))
```

Comment: It would have been better if you have simply did `split()`, since OP wants to match `\s+` :)